# Remove the branding of WP at new posts and new pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress

How to remove the branding of WP at new posts and new pages?

[Click to see the Branding position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qed9j.png)

I tried to use css code

```
.edit-post-fullscreen-mode-close.has-icon {display:none !important;}
```

but it dint workout

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, that the css code of your theme is not applied to the admin area. So the stylesheet will not be overwritten.

Two possible ways to get CSS styles into your wordpress backend:

---

To use a seperate CSS file for wp-admin, you can add this to the functions.php of your theme:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_admin_styles' );

function add_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adminstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/adminstyle.css', false, '1.0.0' );
}
```

Then you have to a add the `adminstyle.css` to your theme folder and do the adjustment you like.

---

Maybe you do not need a seperate file, because you do not want to make many adjustments. You can use other action and add the css code directly inside the function. This also can be placed inside the functions.php file or your theme.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'add_admin_styles');

function add_admin_styles() {
  echo '<style>
    .edit-post-fullscreen-mode-close.has-icon {display:none !important;}
  </style>';
}
```